# Access to the path is Denied When create file by windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

i cannot create file in my windows service 
and this is error

**error In onstart method Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\BridgeServiceLog.txt' is denied.**

```
  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
      {


            try
            {
                 Logger.InitLogFile("BridgeServiceLog.txt");
                 Trace.WriteLine(Logger.logSwitch.TraceInfo, "Trace Started");
                 Trace.WriteLineIf(Logger.logSwitch.TraceInfo, "OnStart Started");

                 _bridgeServiceEventLog.WriteEntry("new OnStart");
                 if (Vytru.Platform.Bridge.Configuration.LicenseValidetor.ValidCountAndTypeDevices())
                 {
                      SharedData.InitializeBridge();
                      // WsInitializeBridge();
                 }
                 else
                 {

                      this.Stop();
                      _bridgeServiceEventLog.WriteEntry("LicenseValidetor Error");
                 }
                 _bridgeServiceEventLog.WriteEntry("end Start");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                 Trace.WriteLineIf(Logger.logSwitch.TraceError, e.Message);
                 _bridgeServiceEventLog.WriteEntry("error In onstart method " + e.Message);
            }
            Trace.WriteLineIf(Logger.logSwitch.TraceInfo, "OnStart Ended");

      }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The service user account probably doesn't have access to write to `C:\Windows\System32` (which is the working directory of a Windows service).

Anyway, you shouldn't write to that folder. It is for the operating system - not your service.

You can use [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) to get a suitable path for writing files like log files in a way that will work any computer, not just your own computer. Here is an example.

```
var companyPath = Path.Combine(
  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData),
  "MyCompany"
);
var productPath = Path.Combine(companyPath, "MyProduct");
var logFilePath = Path.Combine(productPath, "BridgeServiceLog.txt");
```

You should of course use suitable values for `MyCompany` and `MyProduct`.

Answer (score 5):

When running a Windows Service the default working folder is `<System drive>:\Windows\System32\`.
Fortunately, not everyone can just access that folder.

There are two ways about this; write your file to another folder to which you do have rights, or run your service with administrator rights.

I would recommend the first option.

Comment: Go into `services.msc` (Windows key + R) then find your service, right-click go to the Log On tab and configure an administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to go the folder where you want to save a file, right click, properties, security, add a new user IIS_Users and give permission to write.

Answer (score 0):

Use LocalSystem account on ProjectInstaller